# CUDA how to compare two 2D arrays?

Tags: arrays, comparison, cuda

Is there any efficient algorithm to compare two 2D arrays in CUDA as fast as possible? As a result I need a number of array fields that are equal.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the number of equal elements between the two arrays, try a reduce operation.  There is an example of this on NVIDIA's site: [reduction](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/). Normal sum reductions find the sum of all elements in an array `a`.  What you want is the sum of the expression `a == b` for all elements.  You should look articles on CUDA reduction implementations.

Comment: Broken link, sadly. [This](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf), perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

For these types of operations, I'd recommend looking at the http://code.google.com/p/thrust/.

Two relevant operations which might be useful are thrust::transform to construct a boolean array and thrust::count_if to do the reduction.  More efficient techniques with fancy iterators etc. are also possible. Browse around the tutorials.

Comment: Or use `thrust::equal` https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__comparisons_gad90af5f86ba9092cd92c0ae4ebd8d677.html . (Most work will be on adapting the 2D structure to something like thrust can take.)